# Combining Formulas of different types

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to combine all info from a given number of cells into one cell and to convert all of the information in that one cell to uppercase. Is there a way to make this happen?

More specifically, I'm using the formula `=TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, A2:K2)` to combine the info from A2:K2 into one cell (A4). I want the letters that end up in A4 to always be uppercase, no matter how it is entered into A2:K2. Is there a way to add `=UPPER()` to this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

**`=UPPER(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; A2:K2))`**

[image]

Comment: D'oh! For some reason I had only tried using UPPER after TEXTJOIN. Now I feel like a doofus, lol. Thanks for the help, worked perfectly!

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(""; 1; UPPER(A2:K2))` works too, but it will output only cell that is above at given range as uppercased

Comment: This would work as well `=UPPER(CONCATENATE(A2:K2))`